# Is there a way to specify Account metadata in test mode before or after oAuth?

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

After an Account is created through oAuth, attempting to update the metadata fails in test mode saying that it's not allowed. If there's another way to specify account metadata on creation or a way to enable metadata updates for an Account in test mode, that would be great news to hear!

This was attempted using the `stripe-node` sdk's `stripe.accounts.update` resource method to update the metadata.

```
          try {
            await stripe.accounts.update(
              data.stripe_user_id,
              {metadata: {shopId: producerDetails.id}}
            )
          } catch (e) {
            console.log(e.message)
          }
```

Error Message: `Only live keys can access this method.`